# Repetitive For Loops in 2048 Game

Tags: python, game, matrix

I have the following function defined in a program that implements the 2048 game. I tried condensing the repeating part of the code into one loop containing +1 offset variables for the indices, which are either set to 0 or 1 depending on the direction passed into the function, but the outer and inner loop variables swap depending on the direction. Could anyone give me some pointers as to how to condense this code and make it more clean, pythonic and terse?

```
def merge(direction):
    #if adjacent cells are equal, they are merged into one with twice the value and then moved.
    if direction == "up":
        for col in range(nColumns):
            for row in range(nRows-1):
                if grid[row][col] == grid[row+1][col]:
                    grid[row][col] = grid[row+1][col]*2
                    grid[row+1][col] = 0
                    move(direction)

    if direction == "down":
        for col in range(nColumns):
            for row in range(nRows-1):
                if grid[row][col] == grid[row+1][col]:
                    grid[row+1][col] = grid[row][col]*2
                    grid[row][col] = 0
                    move(direction)

    if direction == "left":
        for row in range(nRows):
            for col in range(nColumns-1):
                if grid[row][col] == grid[row][col+1]:
                    grid[row][col] = grid[row][col]*2
                    grid[row][col+1] = 0
                    move(direction)

    if direction == "right":
        for row in range(nRows):
            for col in range(nColumns-1):
                if grid[row][col] == grid[row][col+1]:
                    grid[row][col+1] = grid[row][col]*2
                    grid[row][col] = 0
                    move(direction)
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `if` be more indented?

Comment: @Morwenn The lack of indentation evidently unintentional, so I've fixed it.

Comment: In one implementation I had seen, there was a trick like turning the board in one direction and then in the other in order to deal with moves in only one direction. For instance, if you have implemented "move_down", to do "move_right", you just need to : rotate clockwise, move_down and rotate anti-clockwise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterating more smartly can simplify your loops.

To start with, run this standalone example and see that the `izip(…)` expression produces useful pairs of coordinates:

```
from itertools import product, izip
nRows, nColumns = 3, 5
for dest, src in izip(product(range(nRows - 1), range(nColumns)),
                      product(range(1, nRows), range(nColumns))):
    print(dest, src)
```

Then, you can reuse the loop just by changing which ranges you pass in.

```
from itertools import product, izip

def merge(direction):
    def merge(dest_iterator, src_iterator):
        for (dr, dc), (sr, sc) in izip(dest_iterator, src_iterator):
            if grid[dr][dc] == grid[sr][sc]:
                 grid[dr][dc] == 2 * grid[sr][sc]
                 grid[sr][sc] = 0
                 move(direction)

    if direction == "up":
        merge(product(range(nRows - 1), range(nColumns)),
              product(range(1, nRows), range(nColumns)))
    elif direction == "down":
        merge(product(range(1, nRows), range(nColumns)),
              product(range(nRows - 1), range(nColumns)))
    elif direction == "left":
        merge(product(range(nRows), range(nColumns - 1)),
              product(range(nRows), range(1, nColumns)))
    elif direction == "down":
        merge(product(range(nRows), range(1, nColumns)),
              product(range(nRows), range(nColumns - 1)))
```

Comment: Thank you for acquainting me with itertools. I can't say the solution is completely intuitive yet, but that will come in time.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `dictionary` of `lambda`s to find locations of accepting and donating cells in the grid.. Then place the operations in `try`/`except`, that will simply fail if you go out of bounds

```
GetLocations = dict(
    up = lambda r,c: (r,c,r+1,c ),
    down = lambda r,c: (r+1,c,r,c ),
    right = lambda r,c: (r,c,r,c+1),
    left = lambda r,c: (r,c+1,r,c ))

def merge(direction):
    for col in range(nColumns):
        for row in range(nRows):
            #get acceptor and doner locations
            ar,ac,dr,dc = GetLocations[direction](row,col)
            try:
                #if the evaluation doesn't fail, nothing will fail
                if grid[ar][ac] == grid[dr][dc]:
                    grid[ar][ac] = grid[dr][dc]*2
                    grid[dr][dc] = 0
                    move(direction)
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

Comment: I suggest catching just `IndexError` to avoid swallowing other exceptions.

Comment: I suggest don't making it throw `IndexError` in the first place by checking the bounds before you break them.

Comment: Good call,.. Added it!

Comment: Thank you! This looks like what my approach would have been. I think you got `right` and `left` switched up.